# Mongo Server Status - "Resident" memory

Tags: mongodb

After starting Mongo via `mongod`, I ran a Mongo query that took **300** seconds. Calling `db.serverStatus()` on my "admin" db showed Mongo having [resident](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#server-status-memory) memory of 1 GB. The docs explain that "resident" memory is the amount of physical disk/RAM that Mongo uses.

Then, I re-ran the same query, but it took **8** seconds. Looking at the `resident` memory this time, I saw 5 GB.

The large increase in RAM, I believe, helps to explain why the query time shrank from 300 to 8 seconds, but why did the resident memory jump so quickly?

Is there some type of "warming" step recommended to prepare Mongo so as to avoid 300 second queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There reason behind that MongoDB uses mmap functionality of the operating system. This means, at least on Linux systems That the memory handling of the mongodb is based on some functionality of the operating system called memory mapped files.
The memory in Linux systems is addressed in several levels basically any program will see an address space on 32-bit systems of 2GB over all, on 64-bit systems 128TB. This is a virtual address space which means on 32/64bit that amount of memory can be addressed with 4kb memory pages(page is the individually handled part of the memory).  That is why if you start mongoDB on a 32 bit system it will rise a warning that the database on such system can handle only 2GB of data. Obviously this virtual address space is bigger than the amount of physical memory so there is a mapping between these virtual addresses and the physical ones. Some of the virtual addresses reside in really physical memory so they are in the real memory,but the algorithm which ensures this is on the side of the kernel. Programs running on Linux systems can deal only with virtual addresses, if one tries to access a virtual memory address which is not in physical memory, a pagefault occurs (you can track this on the serverStatus commands extra info field). (You can find short explanation of this [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#what-are-memory-mapped-files))

Accessing memory in case if the virtual address reside in physical memory is as fast as the memory, accessing a virtual address which has no physical currently means a paging from disk to memory and read the memory so as fast as the disks random read. (This makes the different in your case)

There is a command in mongoDB which with you can enforce the caching of a collection or an index this command is the [touch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) 
If you use this command to load the data into memory before the first query you will get the results in 8sec at first try. Unfortunately you cannot really force the OS to keep always this in memory, so if you have others things using up the memory OS will page out this data in some time.

IF you have enough physical memory mongoDB will keep everything the data and indexes in memory. This not always needed. There is a portion of data which need to be in memory to avoid extensive amount of pagefaults this is the [workingset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#what-is-the-working-set). You can check the size of the working set with the [db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1, workingSet: 1 } )](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/#what-is-working-set-and-how-can-i-estimate-it-s-size) command.

You cannot handle the paging while it is OS level, but if you have enough memory usually the kernel likes to keep as much stuff cached as it can. If the workingset fits in memory you are more or less ok. If some documents really rarely accessed and there is not enough memory to keep everything there they will be paged out anyway.

When you run a query several things can happen. An index can cover which means no documents will be touched at all, if your query is selective in some notion only a part of the index will be touched. unfortunately it is really hard to define memory is sufficient and the only thing what you can do is to monitor (the workingset metric is an estimation). The symptom of running out of memory can be identified check this [presentation](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/webinar-performance-tuning-and-monitoring-using-mms). And use [MMS](https://mms.mongodb.com).

Comment: Thanks for that helpful answer. So, attish, if I have enough RAM in memory to only cover only the indexes, page faults can still occur when fetching the non-indexed fields from the found documents?

Comment: The problem have several levels. You can check the working set size i update shortly my answer.

Comment: I updated the workingset related part. I am glad, that could help you.

Comment: hello attish, may I ask you a question?  The link is `https://stackoverflow.com/q/52942750/2922289`. It's about memory release of MongoDB, I hope you can help me. Thank you!